# Taking minimum of two lists

Tags: python, list

I want to create a function `compare_lists` that takes two lists as arguments (which can be empty). It should match the following criterias:

1. If both are empty function should return nothing
2. If first list is empty, and second is not, then return -1
3. If first list is not empty, but second is empty, then return 1
4. If both are not empty, and minimum of first list is smaller than minimum of second list return 1, else return -1.

My code is the following:

```
def compare_lists(list_1, list_2):
    if (len(list_1) > 0) and (len(list_2) == 0):
        return 1
    elif (len(list_1) == 0) and (len(list_2) > 0):
        return -1
    elif (len(list_1) > 0) and (len(list_2) > 0):
        if np.min(list_1) < np.min(list_2):    
            return 1
        else:
            return -1
```

**Example of usage**

```
list_1 = []
list_2 = [2, 3, 4]
print(compare_lists(list_1, list_2))
-1
list_1 = [1, 3, 8]
list_2 = [2, 3, 4]
print(compare_lists(list_1, list_2))
1
```

My question is - do you think it can be done easier, rather than by applying so many conditions?

Comment: Yes, there is an easier way. Is this a homework assignment? If so, your teacher will get suspicious when using advance functions if you didn't learn them already.

Comment: How do you define *easier*? That's really opinion based. I find your function quite easy to understand...

Comment: The `len` checks for knowing if the list is empty or not could be replaced with `if list1` or `if not list1` to know if the list is non-empty or empty respectively

Comment: I don't understand why you've used `np` for such a simple task, you could have simply used builtin `min` function to find minimum or even a custom (if its a homework).

Comment: Didn't get to post my solution before the question was closed, so you can get it in a comment instead... Using the default keyword of the minimum function, you can do the following
`def compare_lists(m1, m2):
    if m1 or m2:
        return int(min(m1, default=float('inf')) < min(m2, default=float('inf')))*2-1`

Comment: Another oneliner: `if list_1 or list_2: return 1 if min(list_1 or [list_2[0]+1]) < min(list_2 or [list_1[0]+1]) else - 1`

Answer (score 1):

A shorter way, with less `if`s and `else`s can be:

```py
def compare_lists(list1, list2):
    if len(list1) != 0 and (len(list2) == 0 or min(list1) < min(list2)):
        return 1
    elif len(list2) != 0:
        return -1
```

It might be less readable though...

Answer (score 1):

My preference is readability over shortness. I would write this function as I read it:

```py
>>> def compare_lists(l1, l2):
...     if not l1 and l2: return -1
...     if l1 and not l2: return 1
...     if l1 and l2:
...         if min(l1) < min(l2):
...             return 1
...         else:
...             return -1
...
>>> list_1 = []
>>> list_2 = [2, 3, 4]
>>> print(compare_lists(list_1, list_2))
-1
>>> list_1 = [1, 3, 8]
>>> list_2 = [2, 3, 4]
>>> print(compare_lists(list_1, list_2))
1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is less readable but has less lines (if that's what you mean by "easier")

```py
def compare_lists(l1, l2):
    d = {(False, False): None, (True, False): 1, (False, True): -1}
    if (bool(l1), bool(l2)) in d: return d[(bool(l1), bool(l2))]
    return (1 if min(l1) < min(l2) else -1)
```